# Jquery -- dialog show() and hide()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have an .aspx page called Default.aspx. I am using a div to show as dialog, my div section is:

```
   <div id="dialog" class="dialogADD" title="Dialog" style="display:none">
     ...
    </div>
```

Here is my Jquery Call, which I use to show and hide the dialog.

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
      function ContextMenuAction(){
         var key = "Add";
      if (key == "Add") {
    $(".dialogADD").dialog({
        height: 238,
        width: 465,
        resizable: false,
        title: "Add Ports"

    });
         AddPortContext($Port); // Here does the functionality of Adding from dialog  
        }// End of ContextMenu



          function AddPortContext($Port) {

            $(".dialogADD").show();

             $(".imgbtnUpdate").click(function () {

                ... // Does some work here

                     success: function (JSONData) {
            try {
                  $(".dialogADD").dialog('close');
                   }
                  }); // Close of click
        }); // Close of Load function
```

This is how I open and close the dialog:
When I click it first time, it works. Second time, it does not work if I do not call show(). If I use show() as it is in above example, it is inserted again, and thrice for third click.

Can any one please help me.

Moreover I am using the same div and same functionalty for both ADD and Update. The same dialog popups for ADD and Update, where iam unable to click it for second time, or getting inserted with each click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think you will be closing and opening the dialog a lot, you could create a toggle function:

```
var isShown = false;
function toggleDialog(){
    if(!isShown){
        $("#dialog").show();
        isShown = true;
    } else {
        $("#dialog").hide();
        isShown = false;
    }
}
```

And if you wanted to get fancy, you could pass in a parameter that sets the message in the dialog.

```
function toggleDialog(string message){...
    ...
    $('#dialog).html(message);
    ...
}
```

Even better would be to just say, if a message is passed in, then show the dialog, otherwise hide it:

```
function toggleDialog(message){
    if(message != null){
        $('#dialog).html(message);
        $("#dialog").show();
    } else {
        $('#dialog).html("");
        $("#dialog").hide();
    }
}
```

Then, to open `toggleDialog("Cool message");` and to close `toggleDialog(null);`

Answer (score 0):

Remove your **function definitions** inside the onload(document.ready).

`$(".dialogADD").show();`

This statement will not work for diplaying the dialog.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    });
```

This is strictly for onload.